# Homescreen Web Application and AD Authentication

Tags: ios, html, authentication, cache-manifest, offlineapps

I have an HTML5 website which has AD authentication. Inside this website, I have a webpage which I would like to be a "web app" on an iPad.

I have the cache.appcache file all ready and working fine in an environment where there is no AD authentication.

When I go to the page on the iPad, authenticate and then add to Home Screen, everything seems fine.

When I click on the homescreen shortcut, the page asks for authentication again. I need this to be an offline app - how can I achieve this? I want the user to have to authenticate to get the web app "installed" on the homescreen but after that don't want them to have to authenticate again.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Could you please paste your problem code.

Comment: Hi, it's not so much a coding issue - the code works absolutely fine on iPad when I don't have the html file in an authenticated environment. As soon as I put the files into an authenticated environment, the offline mode doesn't work

Comment: What is AD authentication? Perhaps users are unsure how your web app is being authenticated, and therefore don't know how to answer your question.